# return Roles with GetUserInfo method asp.net WebAPI2.0 with EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, roles

i have implemented Rolemanager as explained here:
http://johnatten.com/2014/10/26/asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2-0-customizing-identity-models-and-implementing-role-based-authorization/

now i need the API to return the Roles from the webAPI to the "client"(which is another ASP.net site acting as the frontend) so i can see which views i should hide from users that are not admin.

can i add the roles to the GetUserInfo method in the Accounts controller, or should i go about it a different way, and how should I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up implementing it like this in the AccountController:

```
public UserInfoViewModel GetUserInfo()
    {
        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
        var rols = ((ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
            .Select(c => c.Value);

        var UIM = new UserInfoViewModel
        {
            Email = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
            HasRegistered = externalLogin == null,
            LoginProvider = externalLogin != null ? externalLogin.LoginProvider : null,
            roles = rols
        };
        return UIM;
    }
```

and then adding this to the UserInfoViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<string> roles;
```